# virtual function is not called c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm having:

```
class DeliveryVehicle{
public:
    //c'tor
    DeliveryVehicle(const char* ID, Quality quality);

    //d'tor
    virtual ~DeliveryVehicle();

    int performDeliveryDay(int* numberOfDeliveries);
    ...
protected:
    ...                 

        /* PrintDailySummary: here numberOfDeliveries is a "dummy" parameter but 
        it would be used in the ProfessionalDeliveryVehicle overriding function */
        virtual void PrintDailySummary(int dailyProfit, int numberOfDeliveries = 0) const;
};
```

As can be seen performDeliveryDay() is a non-virtual function and only the printing function is virtual, for I want to print extra information in the derived type.

**Virtual PrintDailySummary() is called inside the non-virtual function performDeliveryDay()**

[I don't add the implementation of performDeliveryDay() - if it is relevant I will edit my post]

Additionally I'm having derived class:

```
class ProfessionalDeliveryVehicle:public DeliveryVehicle {
public:
    //c'tor
    ProfessionalDeliveryVehicle(const char* ID, Quality quality):
                                DeliveryVehicle(ID,quality) {}

    //d'tor
    // Vehicle destructor is called by default

protected:
    void PrintDailySummary(int dailyProfit, int numberOfDeliveries);
};
```

The implementation of the printing function in the derived class is:

```
void ProfessionalDeliveryVehicle::PrintDailySummary(int dailyProfit, int numberOfDeliveries){
    DeliveryVehicle::PrintDailySummary(dailyProfit, numberOfDeliveries);

    // print some extra statistics
}
```

within the program I have a queue of base pointers that may point to base or derived class.

For each element in the queue I call the function performDeliveryDay().
I expected to see the extra printing for the derived class objects. 
From some reason I don't see them, only the printing of the base method.
When I put breakpoint inside the printing function of the derived class I saw it doesn't even entered.

Can someone point my problem?
thanks

**EDIT:** Etienne Maheu pointed out the problem. 
There was a mismatch between the printing functions - "const" part - signature.
The problem was solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your derived class's virtual method does not have the same signature. It is missing the `const` qualifier. Might also want to specifiy the default value depending on your usage.

```
virtual void PrintDailySummary(int dailyProfit, int numberOfDeliveries = 0) const;

void PrintDailySummary(int dailyProfit, int numberOfDeliveries);
```

Note: if you are using C++11, you might want to use `override` keyword to declare your override intention to the compiler. This will help catch such bugs at compile time.

Comment: This is why in C++11 one should always use [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) on a function that is intended to override a virtual. That will cause the compiler to complain about errors like this.

Comment: Using [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) would have prevented this error.

Comment: so actually I just hided the virtual function (by mistake) instead of overriding it?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer: Correct.